# News clustering in Python using fastcluster module

Tags: python, scipy, hierarchical-clustering

I am trying to write a news aggregator in Python. I take the news articles, make the term-document matrix and then I cluster them using cosine similarity with the help of *scipy* and *fascluster* module:

```
distance = spatial.distance.pdist(wordmatrix,'cosine')
linkage = fastcluster.linkage(distance,method="complete")
```

It works great when I have around 30 news sources. But at the moment when I put around 70 different sources, it doesn't cluster well. I tried to normalize the term-document matrix and I tried also the tf-idf matrix, but I still have the same result. Any idea how can I solve this problem?

Comment: Have you tried getting rid of stop words before computing the tf-idf?

Comment: Yes, I remove the stop words from the beginning

Comment: I also use only words that appear in more then 3 articles, and in less then 70% of articles

Comment: You could try cosine similarity on LSA vectors (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latent_semantic_analysis ) than tf-idf. Topic models such as LDA might work even better.

Comment: Thank you, seems worth checking out